# Different length of NSAttributedString and corresponding NSString in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uitextview

I'm using [RichTextEditor](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Rich-Text-Editor).
I had to customise it a bit, but there is no significant changes.
I'm setting converting `html` into `NSAttributedString` using `DTCoreText` and displaying it in the subclass of `UITextView`, named `RichTextEditor`, mentioned above.
So here is the issue:
If I make a string with paragraphs (separated with `'\n'`), the length of `richTextEditor.attributedText.string` differs from `richTextEditor.text` in the following manner:

```
(lldb) **po [self.attributedText.string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\\n\n"]**  
Grftfvtfc\n  
Difg hdfigdfg df\n  
Hgcytvuyg\n  
Sdkjf sdfs sdf klsdf sf kjsdfk s fsdfh s&apos;dfjshdf sdfjshdf sdjfh sdfsjd sdf\n  
Sdfj sdkfjsdl[kak sdfkjsdk sdfksd&apos; kh&apos;dfjs sfsdfsdfsdfUfvutfvuggvjgfc\n  


(lldb) **po [self.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\\n\n"]**  
Grftfvtfc\n  
\n  
Difg hdfigdfg df\n  
\n  
Hgcytvuyg\n  
\n  
Sdkjf sdfs sdf klsdf sf kjsdfk s fsdfh s&apos;dfjshdf sdfjshdf sdjfh sdfsjd sdf\n  
\n  
Sdfj sdkfjsdl[kak sdfkjsdk sdfksd&apos; kh&apos;dfjs sfsdfsdfsdfUfvutfvuggvjgfc
```

Sometimes `richTextEditor.text` has two `'\n'` symbols, but at the end of the document it might not contain even a single `'\n'`.

This bug is relevant for `iOS6` only. Under `iOS7` everything works like a charm. What can be the possible reason?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared, that the thing was in `NSParagraphStyle` and its properties paragraphSpacing. If you make it big enough - the textview adds extra `\n` symbols to increase the distance between paragraphs, but the string itself doesn't contain those `\n`'s.